# Create criteria from sub query

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, criteria

I am trying to convert my query to Criteria where I am facing issues. Below is the query which I am trying to convert

```
SELECT 
    machine_type_id,
    machine_type,
    user_name
FROM
    nc_machine_types
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN
            TRIM(':q') = ''
                OR ':q' IS NULL
        THEN
            machine_type IS NOT NULL
        ELSE (machine_type = ':q'
            OR machine_type_id = (SELECT 
                machine_type_id
            FROM
                nc_machine_screen
            WHERE
                machine_no = ':q'))
    END
```

The predicate I can convert now is

```
return new Specification<MachineType>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MachineType> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();             

            if(!StringUtils.isBlank(q)) {

                Subquery<Long> ordersSubquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
                    Root rootB = ordersSubquery.from(Mahine.class);

         ordersSubquery.select(rootB.get("machineType").get("machineTypeId"));
                        ordersSubquery.where(cb.equal(rootB.get("machineNo"), q));


                        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("machineType"), q));
                cb.or(cb.equal(root.get("machineId"), ordersSubquery));
            }
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        }
};
```

The query which is getting constructed is like

```
select machine_type_id, user_name, machine_type from machine_types where machine_type=?
```

The `OR` clause is not coming in the query. How can I add it in the query?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I can simply remove

```
predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("machineType"), q));
cb.or(cb.equal(root.get("machineId"), ordersSubquery));
```

and add

```
cb.or(cb.equal(root.get("machineType"), q), cb.equal(root.get("machineId"), ordersSubquery));
```